Inward/outward spiral character in latex
I expect the answer is "you can't do this", but I often use an inward/outward spiral as shorthand for saying "this series/sequence converges/diverges": 
I'm trying to move my formula sheet from a handwritten one to latex, and I don't know what to do for this symbol. Is there a Latex symbol for an inwards/outwards spiral? Is there anything else I could do?
Thanks

I'm not sure of the usage so you might want to enclose the macros in \mathbin or mathrel, but here is a start.
The scalerel* command is used to scale the arrows to the ( character, so it will adjust if used in a subscript.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\divarrow}{\scalerel*{\tikz[xscale=-1]{\useasboundingbox(-.2,-.2)rectangle(.3,.3);
    \draw [line width=.6, -{[length=2]>}, line cap=round, domain=90:465 ,variable=\t, smooth, samples=30] plot (\t: 0.0005*\t);}}{(}
}
\newcommand{\convarrow}{\scalerel*{\tikz[xscale=-1]{\useasboundingbox(-.2,-.2)rectangle(.3,.3);
    \draw[line width=.6, line cap=round, domain=90:465 ,variable=\t, smooth, samples=30] plot (\t: 0.0005*\t);
    \path[decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .1 with {\arrow{[line width=.6, length=2]>}}}, ](75:.045)--++(-15:.1);}}{(}
}

\begin{document}

$\{a_n\}\convarrow\divarrow$

\end{document}


That is absolutely amazing, I changed some of the presets. I am using:
\newcommand{\divarrow}{\scalerel*{\tikz[xscale=-1]{\useasboundingbox(-.2,-.2)rectangle(.3,.3);
\draw [line width=1.00, -{[length=2.5]>}, line cap=round, domain=20:475 ,variable=\t, smooth, samples=30] plot (\t: 0.00050*\t);}}{(}
}

And:
\newcommand{\convarrow}{\scalerel*{\tikz[xscale=-1]{\useasboundingbox(-.2,-.2)rectangle(.3,.3);
\draw[line width=1.00, line cap=round, domain=90:465 ,variable=\t, smooth, samples=30] plot (\t: 0.00055*\t);
\pathdecorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .1 with {\arrow{[line width=1.0, length=2.5]>}}}, --++(-15:.6);}}{(}
}
